# Yii2.0 - Ajax form submit and dropdown update

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I have a model with a category relation. In my model form i have dropdown to choose from existing categories, and a modal popup for adding additional categories. But the modal submit reloads the page to insert and update.

Now, id like the modal submit button to close the modal, submit the form trough ajax and update the dropdown field.

I remember doing this in Yii 1.1, is there a neat way to do this in Yii2.0? Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually submit the form with ajax also. All you need to do is listen to `beforeSubmit` event in javascript.

An example of such implementation is available in this [issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5991).

Also you can find some docs about this and other yii `ActiveForm` javascript events [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L82).

Hope it helps.